# Creating a page from a master/layout using VS deploy (unable to add webparts workaround)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I'm starting with Sharepoint. This may be basic but I appreciate your help.

My project is deployable via visual studio 2010.

I have a index.aspx that calls a layout (master) page and have a webpart

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" masterpagefile="../_catalogs/masterpage/MyMaster.master"     title="Example" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,    Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9499c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" %>
[…]
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="WebPartZone1">
            <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
        </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</asp:Content>
```

My user is unable to add webparts on his environment. When he edits the page, the webpartzone added doesn't appear.

They give me some advice:

They told me that, in visual studio, when they deploy a solution, to potentially avoid this issue, I should:

- Create a custom page layout and upload it on the masters page /_catalogs/masterPage (I think I've done it as my layout page Mymaster.Master is currently located there
- Once I do it I create in the page library one page based on this layout.

How can I accomplish that in VS? (or even, not in Visual Studio, just to know).
I just know THIS way (the simple one) of creating pages!..

Thanks!

Javi